# Hammer.js scrolling activates drag right functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, hammer.js

I am working on my first touch project and I am using Backbone and RequireJS as the framework to the site. I am using Hammer.js as the touch library to allow me to drag open additional content.

The site has a grid layout with a simple 3 box pattern. The first box is the full width of the screen, and then the other two boxes sit directly below it at 50% of the width.

The problem I am running into is as I use my phone (iPhone 4S and Nexus 5) to scroll down to additional content (We use a lazy load to add to the grid layout) Hammer.js fires the drag right or drag left event.

I assume this is because my thumb veers off near the end of the scroll. Is there a way to prevent this functionality? Like if the drag right also has a drag up, it doesn't fire.

The code I am using is the following:

```
$('.tile').hammer().bind("dragright", function(event){
   event.gesture.preventDefault();
   console.log("The event type is: " + event.type)

   if ($(this).children('.desc').hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).children('.desc').removeClass('active');
   }
   else
   {
      $(this).children('.title').addClass('active');
   }
});
```

Any help with this would be wonderful. I have tried looking through Stack Overflow already but I don't think I am using the right terminology as I haven't had too much success finding the information I am looking for.

Thanks so much,
Andrew